# R: order top 10 of result "means" and output results as .csv

Tags: r, csv

I have database: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0zK9xcdOi1sMUE3LTVMQVlXU28/view?usp=sharing)

```
fun_mean <- function(x){return(round(data.frame(y=mean(x),label=mean(x,na.rm=T)),digit=2))}

foo <- qplot(Interest, Scored.Probabilities, data = dataset1, geom = "boxplot"); 
foo <- foo+stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point",colour="darkred",size=3)+stat_summary(fun.data = fun_mean,geom="text", vjust=-0.7)
ggsave(foo, file="Interest.png", width=20, height=7)
```

[image]

There are so mach information, I want only top 10 by mean values (output new .png) and could I output all the mean value table as .csv?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)

fun_mean <- function(x){return(round(data.frame(y=mean(x),label=mean(x,na.rm=T)),digit=2))}

m <- dataset1 %>% group_by(Interest) %>%
                  summarize(y=mean(Scored.Probabilities),
                           label=mean(Scored.Probabilities,na.rm=T)) %>%
                  arrange(desc(y))

idx <- as.character(m$Interest[1:10])

dataset2 <- filter(dataset1,Interest %in% idx)

foo <- qplot(Interest, Scored.Probabilities, data = dataset2, geom = "boxplot"); 
foo <- foo + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point",colour="darkred",size=3) +
             stat_summary(fun.data = fun_mean,geom="text", vjust=-0.7) +
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the plotting function, but I guess you need to define, which of them are top 10, something like this could work...

```
selectedMeans <- which(fun_mean %in% sort(fun_mean)[1:10])
```

Than I would use parameter `subset = selectedMeans`, but I am not sure if this plotting function can do it... Otherwise I would create new subtable of selected data...